# C++ using fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

Ok so I haven't used C++ since highschool (used to work in borland C++)

Now I want to solve a problem in C++, yet I don't understand why fstream doesn't work

For some reason ios::in doesn't work.

```
#include <fstream>
fstream f("Cities.txt,ios::in);
```

How do I use Fstream properly?

Thanks in advance!

Note : I'm using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: First: Terminate the Filename with another '"'.

Answer (score 4):

change from

```
fstream f("Cities.txt,ios::in);
```

to

```
std::fstream f("Cities.txt" , std::ios::in);
^^^                       ^   ^^^
namespace          you miss"  namespace
```

done!

Answer (score 2):

What you have learned in your highschool probably was way before C++ was standardized in '97. As per the standard, all C++ library functions are part of the std namespace. In order to use fstream which is part of the standard namespace, you have to qualify it with std:: so, that makes your syntax as

```
#include <fstream>
std::fstream f("Cities.txt",std::ios::in);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to first create an object of `ifstream` class and then open the file.
Do it this way.

```
#include <fstream>

std :: ifstream f ("Cities.txt",ios::in) ;
```

Then check whether it is open and start working with it.

You are also missing the `"` after file name.

Comment: Don't get in the habit of using `using namespace std;`. Apart from the most trivial of examples it is counter productive.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [`std::fstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream), consider [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) (and [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream)):

```
#include <fstream>

…

std::ifstream f("Cities.txt");
std::ofstream o("output.txt");
std::string s;
while( f >> s )
  o << s;
```

Personally, I find this more convenient than specifying the [open mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode).

Answer (score 0):

You can also write

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
fstream f("Cities.txt",ios::in);
```

The `using` directive allows you to not write `std::` before everything. Beware, it might be bad practice, but in small programs it should not be an issue.