# C++ can't open file after created

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program then open it by using this code.

```
//Make the file
std::ifstream  src(a, std::ios::binary);
std::ofstream  dst(b, std::ios::binary);

dst << src.rdbuf();

//Execute it
Execute((LPCTSTR)b.c_str());
```

Function Execute:

```
bool Execute(LPCTSTR Process)
{
STARTUPINFO         sInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;

ZeroMemory(&sInfo, sizeof(sInfo));

sInfo.cb = sizeof(sInfo);

ZeroMemory(&pInfo, sizeof(pInfo));

if (!CreateProcess(Process, "open", NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &sInfo, &pInfo))
{
    return 0;
}

return 1;
}
```

I have tested making the file and it works when i open the file manualy nothing goes wrong. I tried the execute function and it works fine not a single problem. But when I combined those 2 for some reason it will not execute.

If somebody could tell me why and/or how to fix it that would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and discuss what you learned from single-stepping through your code with the debugger. People are more likely to answer if you've followed the [**guidelines**](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for posting questions. They're serious. You have to demonstrate that you've put some minimal effort into it -- like using your debugger, stripping the code down to its essence to see whether the problem still happens, etc. See the guidelines. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ using fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321644/c-using-fstream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well type the full answer. Basically if the `ofstream` is not closed, the `createProcess` fails. Here is the sample code to test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

bool Execute(LPCTSTR Process)
{
    STARTUPINFO sInfo = {};
    sInfo.cb = sizeof(sInfo);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo = {};

    return CreateProcess(Process, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, NULL, NULL, &sInfo, &pInfo);
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring src_name(L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe");
    std::wstring dst_name(L"C:\\Users\\KK\\Desktop\\mynotepad.exe");

    std::ifstream src(src_name, std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream dst(dst_name, std::ios::binary);

    dst << src.rdbuf();

    src.close();
    dst.close(); // has to be closed before execution

    if (!Execute(dst_name.c_str()))
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Commenting out `dst.close();` produces error.

Answer (score 0):

Question is solved and it turned out to be really simple which was that i just had to close the stream as "Killzone Kid" pointed out.